# Can I modify a toy RC transmitter?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-motor, transmitter, remote-control

I'd like to modify a cheap supermarket RC toy car to go reasonably slower for extended run time and easier control. (would be present to a kid) I have not bought or even selected the toy in question, so we are talking in general.
I have no experience in electrical engineering so my haphazardly collected ideas might be wrong. The DC motor is supplied by a PWM controller. It also has (presumably) a low voltage cutoff function to protect the batteries, so rearranging them in parallel, although a great solution, wouldn't work.
My first thought was a resistor in series with the motor, however, I fear that it would drain the batteries, and only make it go slower while playtime would not double. **Is that true?**
The second option would be to insert a DC regulator IC between the DC motor and the controller to reduce voltage. While it's discouraged to use something like an LM317 for regulating a DC motor, if it solves the problem, I'm up for it. **My question: can this method accomplish both slower motor rpm AND extended battery run time?**
My last idea was to fiddle with the RC transmitter. **My question: can the "requested duty-cycle" emitted by the RF transmitter be adjusted in any way? Does it depend on some input or reference voltage in the handheld device?** I have access to a couple of resistors, potentiometers and ICs, however, this is a micro-budget project, so please guide me accordingly.

Comment: `The DC motor is supplied by a PWM controller` ... are you certain?

Comment: `Does it depend on some input or reference voltage in the handheld device?` ... the device is unknown ... the wording of the question makes it un-answerable

Comment: Why not just change the gearing? Lower speed, less torque demand on the motor giving lower current draw. You can 3d print gears or find them from hobby suppliers.

Comment: If there is a speed potentiometer in the transmitter, you can add a resistor at one end of the potentiometer to limit the voltage range and hope the best. Everything else is speculation. Very cheap RC toys often only have on/off switches.